# .NET Core RedirectToAction causes InvalidOperationException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a page located in:

1. An Area called Action
2. A Controller called Message
3. A Method called Index

When I log into my application, I go to the HomeController which then redirects me like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Messages", new { area = "Action" });
}
```

However, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToActionResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, RedirectToActionResult result)

Its very long but I found that it has something to do with my last await.next() line in my Startup.cs:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        context.Request.Path = "/Error/404";
        await next();
    }
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        context.Request.Path = "/Error/401";
        await next();
    }

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && !context.Response.HasStarted && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        context.Request.Path = "/Error/302";
        await next();
    }
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 400 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        context.Request.Path = "/Error/400";
        await next();
    }
    await next();
});
```

This is my routing in Startup.cs also:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "areas",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```

I have this exact Startup.cs in other applications and they run just fine. Not sure whats wrong with this one?

EDIT:

The full exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToActionResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, RedirectToActionResult result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
>   result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
>   bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context) SendEx.Startup+<>c+<b__2_0>d.MoveNext() in
>   Startup.cs
>   +
>                   await next(); Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

EDIT 2:

When I removed the redirecttoaction and replaced it with a return Page(); The page loads. That means that the area redirection isn't working?

Comment: it is a typo for controller Message and in route Messages ??

Comment: Nope, I checked it again. Maybe I'll delete and remake it.

Comment: I tried another controller and its all the same. Something is wrong with my Startup I guess?

Comment: here you mention  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Messages", new { area = "Action" });    "Messages" and in que description  Controller called "Message"  extra s is it typo error?

Comment: No. The controller is called MessagesController

Comment: I tried linking to other controllers as well but its the same result

Comment: I also don't know exactly it looks all correct, In  302 status code 
 remove context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and check

Comment: Same error occurs when I remove it. I also removed the entire block of error redirection codes and still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one route. Try like below:-

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:new[] {"MVCDemo.Controllers"}
        );
```

Comment: Sorry, my app uses areas so I'll need to include both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Messages", new { area = "Action" });
```

this will have a route like - Messages/Index/Action
so please check what you want and whether that is aligned with the parameters or not.

If you need just Mssage/ or just Index/ create new route config for that.